# How to convert a string in lambda to decimal?

Tags: string, linq, lambda, decimal

I have the code

```
    myEntities db = new myEntities();
    var query = from s in db.mytable select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
      query = query.Where(p => p.total == str);
    }
```

Here, the type of "total" is a string containing numbers and characters, e.g. "14x56xz". I want to get the number part (e.g. 1456)  from the "total" string and convert it to a decimal number, sometimes with the need to turn it into a negative number, making the code look like this:

```
    query = query.Where(10 <= p => p.total <= 1000);
```

I have written a class to process it, but I don't know how to invoke this processing method in Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse it in the lambda. For example:

```
query = query.Where(10 <= p => decimal.Parse(p.total) <= 1000m);
```

Of course, if there's any way you can improve your data model so that logically-numeric values are *stored* as numbers, that would be even better...

EDIT: I think you'll have a hard time converting "14x56xz" to 1456 in LINQ to Entities. You may be able to do something at the database side to expose a computed column using conversions and regular expressions etc, but I'm not sure that you'd be able to express that in LINQ in a way which will be converted appropriately.

Comment: thanks, Jon! i'm sorry I have not made myself clear. The "total" is composed by numbers and characters, first of all, i want to process the "total" field , then the compare it with decimals. i have write a mehthod to process this field, but i do not konw how to invoke this method in lambda.

Comment: @Tom: You still haven't really made it clear either what the method looks like, or what the input looks like, or what you're doing with it. You also need to say whether you're using LINQ to SQL or something similar, or LINQ to Objects - it makes a huge difference in terms of whether you'll be able to use your method.

Comment: hi,Joh. I am uing the Linq to Entity and I'm a newbie about that. I have revised the question. Thank u a lot!